# Загрузка большого видео-файла (более 2 гб) asp net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fileupload

Есть необходимость загружать на сервер со стороны клиента большие видео-ролики (доступ к загрузке у узкого круга лиц, не более 10 чел.) размером более 2 гб.

Дефолтная загрузка на аспе не позволяет загружать более 2 гб (в webconfig ограничение - макс 1.99 гб)

Было предположение на клиенте js-ом 'резать' файл на части и отправлять, на сервере же записывать, но примеров подобных не нашел.

Взываю к вашей помощи в решении данного вопроса. Ссылки, направления на статьи - что угодно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно кому-то будет интересно решение, что тогда я нашел\составил. Сейчас же считаю, что оно не совсем корректное, пусть и работает как требуется. Но недочетов крайне много (например нагрузка на сервер).

**Крайне не рекомендую** использовать его как финальное. Только как идейное вдохновение или базу для разработки.

Прилагаю код клиента и сервера

```js
$(function () {
    var file,
        filename;

    var userName = '@ViewBag.UserName',
        hash = '@ViewBag.Hash';

    var declaredChunkSize = @ViewBag.ChunkSize,
        chunkSize = declaredChunkSize * 1024 * 1024,
        chunkNumber = 0,
        chunk;

    var partialUploadUrl = '@Url.Action("UploadPartial")',
        uploadCompleteUrl = '@Url.Action("UploadComplete")',
        newFileNameUrl = '@Url.Action("GenerateHashName")',
        cleanUpUrl = '@Url.Action("CleanUp")',
        startEditingUrl = '@Url.Action("EditVideo")';

    $('#file-upload').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this)[0].files.length > 0){
            file = $(this)[0].files[0];
            $('#btn-upload').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });

    $(window).on('unload', function (e) {
        console.log('page unloading. disposing temp dir')  ;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: cleanUpUrl,
            data: {
                UserName: userName,
                Oid: hash,
            },
        });
    });

    RequestFileName = function(ext){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: newFileNameUrl,
            async: false,
            data: {
                extension : ext,
            },
            success: function(response){
                filename = response.Name;
                console.log('new name: '+filename);
            }
        });
    };

    start = function(){
        var ext = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        RequestFileName(ext);

        UploadFile();
    };

    $('#btn-upload').click(function () {
        if (file){
            $('#loader').slideUp('slow');
            $('#loading-bar').show('slow');
            console.log('start uploading');

            $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
                return 'Вы уверены, что хотите покинуть страницу?\nНесохраненные данные будут утеряны.'; // not all browsers supported that text
            });
            setTimeout(start, 2 * 1000);
        }
    });

    UploadFile = function () {
        var size = file.size;
        var count = Math.round(size / chunkSize) + 1;

        var start = 0,
            end = chunkSize;

        while ((chunkNumber < count) /*&& !sendingFailed */) {

            chunk = file.slice(start, end);

            var data = new FormData();

            data.append('chunk', chunk);
            data.append('chunkNumber', chunkNumber);
            data.append('fileName', filename);
            data.append('userName', userName);
            data.append('hash', hash);

            $.ajax({
                url: partialUploadUrl,
                type: 'POST',

                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,

                success: function(response){
                },
            });

            ++chunkNumber;

            start = end;
            end = end + chunkSize;
        }

        UploadComplete(count);
    }

    UploadComplete = function (count) {

        $.ajax({
            url: uploadCompleteUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                fileName: filename,
                chunksCount: count,
                userName: userName,
                hash: hash,
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success) {
                    $.growl.notice({title: 'Успешно', message: 'Видео загружено. Идет обработка..'});
                    StartEditingUploadedVideo(result.Id);
                }
                else {
                    $.growl.error({title: 'Неудачно', message: 'Во время загрузки видео произошла ошибка'});
                }
            },
            error: function (response, status, error) {
                $.growl.error({ title: 'Ошибка', message: (error || status) });
            },
        });
    };

    StartEditingUploadedVideo = function(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: startEditingUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                id: id,
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#loading-bar').slideUp('slow');
                $('#main').html(response);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

```cs
public ActionResult UploadPartial(HttpPostedFileBase chunk, int chunkNumber, string fileName, string userName, string hash) 
{
    try
    {
        var configPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Video:RelativePath"];

        var resultedPath = Server.MapPath(configPath);

        var tempFolder = Path.Combine(resultedPath, "Temp", userName, hash);

        var path = Path.Combine(tempFolder, chunkNumber + ".tmp");

        chunk.SaveAs(path);
        return Json(new { Succeeded = true });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { Succeeded = false, Error = e.Message });
    }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> UploadComplete(string fileName, int chunksCount, string userName, string hash) 
{
    var configPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Video:RelativePath"];
    var resultedPath = Server.MapPath(configPath);
    var tempFolder = Path.Combine(resultedPath, "Temp", userName, hash);
    var dest = Path.Combine(resultedPath, fileName);

    for (int i = 0; i < chunksCount; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(tempFolder, i.ToString() + ".tmp");
            Combine(path, dest);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
            i--;
            continue;
        }

    }

    Logger.Info("{0}: Загрузка нового видео [{1}]", userName, fileName);

    #region save video info

    try
    {
        string defaultVideoCatName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaults:VideoCategory"],
               ffmpegTemp = Server.MapPath(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ffmpeg:WorkingPath"]);

        VideoCategory videoCat = RepManager.VideoCategories.GetByPredicateSingle(cat => cat.Name == defaultVideoCatName);
        ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);

        var video = Video.CreateDefault(dest, user, videoCat);

        using (var ffmpegWorker = FFMpegWorker.Create(ffmpegTemp))
            video.Duration = ffmpegWorker.GetVideoInfo(video.Path).Duration;

        RepManager.Videos.Add(video);
        await RepManager.SaveChangesAsync();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CleanUp(userName, Guid.Parse(hash)));

        Logger.Info("{0}: Загрузка нового видео [{1}]: Успешно [id: {2}]", userName, fileName, video.Id);

        return Json(new { Success = true, Id = video.Id });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { Success = false, Error = e.Message });
    }

    #endregion
}

void Combine(string src, string dest) 
{
    byte[] bytes = FileIO.ReadAllBytes(src);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Append))
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    FileIO.Delete(src);
}

public void CleanUp(string UserName, Guid Oid) 
{
    var configPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Video:RelativePath"];
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(configPath), UserName, Oid.ToString());

    if (Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.Delete(path, recursive: true);
}

public ActionResult GenerateHashName(string extension) 
{
    var resultedPath = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + "." + extension;
    return Json(new { Name = resultedPath }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```